# Connecting to master spark://spark-master:7077 All masters are unresponsive! Giving up

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, docker-compose, dockerfile, airflow

I'm trying to run an Airflow DAG, using Kafka as producer and consumer.

Once my producer is working my consumer doesn't  work at all.

This is  how my docker-compose.yaml and Dockerfile's are organized:

[image]

**This is the connection that i setup on Airflow:**
[image]

**This is my DAG using my connection:**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/airflow/dags/src/dag/tasks')

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.apache.spark.operators.spark_submit import SparkSubmitOperator


from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from consumer import *

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 1, 9),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'workflow',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1)
)

t1 = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='spark_submit_task',
    application='/opt/airflow/dags/src/dag/tasks/consumer.py',
    conn_id='spark_docker',
    dag=dag
)
```

**1) Here, is my docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13  
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data


  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - zookeeper_data:/data
      - zookeeper_datalog:/datalog

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "transactions:1:1"           
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092                        
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    volumes:
      - kafka_data:/var/lib/kafka/data

  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    build: ./spark
    ports:
      - "7077:7077"
      - "8081:8080"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - JAVA_HOME=/opt/bitnami/java
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no


  airflow:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Local
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=False
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=sqlite:////opt/airflow/airflow.db
      - AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__RBAC=True
      - AIRFLOW_UID=50000
      - AIRFLOW_VAR_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=["kafka:9092"]
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    volumes:
      - ./sensor:/opt/airflow/dags
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
  zookeeper_datalog:
  kafka_data:
  airflow_data:
  postgres_data:
```

**2) here the Dockerfile that i use for install Airflow:**

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.2

USER root

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
    && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

USER airflow

RUN pip install kafka-python pyspark apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark psycopg2-binary  # Add psycopg2-binary for PostgreSQL support

# Update the Airflow database connection URL to use PostgreSQL
RUN airflow db init \
    && airflow connections add --conn-uri 'postgres://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow' --conn-id 'postgres_default' --conn-type 'Postgres'

# Create other Airflow configurations as needed

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "spark-config.sh"]

CMD ["bash", "-c", "(airflow webserver &) && airflow scheduler"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

**3) Here the Dockerfile that i use for install the pyspark:**

```
FROM bitnami/spark:latest


USER root


ARG APP_FOLDER=/opt/bitnami/spark/app


COPY . ${APP_FOLDER}


WORKDIR ${APP_FOLDER}


RUN pip install py4j pyspark


ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/opt/bitnami/spark/app/spark-config.sh"]

CMD [ "" ]
```

And finally here, the spark-config.sh that both Dockerfiles call for configure the pyspark:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /opt/bitnami/scripts/spark/entrypoint.sh /opt/bitnami/scripts/spark/run.sh &
# wait 10s before trying to submit the job
sleep 10

# Specify the Spark Master URL
SPARK_MASTER_URL="spark://master-ip:7077"

# submit Python application to Spark with the specified master URL
${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit \
      --master "$SPARK_MASTER_URL" \
      --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 \
      "${SPARK_HOME}/app/main.py"


The message error i'm having on my consumer is that below:

*** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/workflow/spark_submit_task/2024-01-10T10:41:29.301626+00:00/1.log
[2024-01-10 10:41:33,248] {taskinstance.py:896} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: workflow.spark_submit_task 2024-01-10T10:41:29.301626+00:00 [queued]>
[2024-01-10 10:41:33,255] {taskinstance.py:896} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: workflow.spark_submit_task 2024-01-10T10:41:29.301626+00:00 [queued]>
[2024-01-10 10:41:33,256] {taskinstance.py:1087} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2024-01-10 10:41:33,256] {taskinstance.py:1088} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2024-01-10 10:41:33,256] {taskinstance.py:1089} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2024-01-10 10:41:33,266] {taskinstance.py:1107} INFO - Executing <Task(SparkSubmitOperator): spark_submit_task> on 2024-01-10T10:41:29.301626+00:00
[2024-01-10 10:41:33,269] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 442 to run task
[2024-01-10 10:41:33,273] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'workflow', 'spark_submit_task', '2024-01-10T10:41:29.301626+00:00', '--job-id', '7', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/src/dag/workflow.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpv_6q7w12', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpkw9dk5a7']
[2024-01-10 10:41:33,275] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 7: Subtask spark_submit_task
[2024-01-10 10:41:33,299] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: workflow.spark_submit_task 2024-01-10T10:41:29.301626+00:00 [running]> on host 84e9b84d3cce
[2024-01-10 10:41:33,329] {taskinstance.py:1302} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=workflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=spark_submit_task
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2024-01-10T10:41:29.301626+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2024-01-10T10:41:29.301626+00:00
[2024-01-10 10:41:33,333] {base.py:78} INFO - Using connection to: id: spark_docker. Host: spark://spark-master, Port: 7077, Schema: , Login: ***, Password: ***, extra: {}
[2024-01-10 10:41:33,335] {spark_submit.py:335} INFO - Spark-Submit cmd: spark-submit --master spark://spark-master:7077 --name arrow-spark /opt/***/dags/src/dag/tasks/consumer.py
[2024-01-10 10:41:33,485] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - /home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 68: ps: command not found
[2024-01-10 10:41:34,573] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
[2024-01-10 10:41:34,573] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.2.4.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
[2024-01-10 10:41:34,573] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
[2024-01-10 10:41:34,573] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
[2024-01-10 10:41:34,574] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,065] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,079] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.2.4
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,175] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,346] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,347] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,348] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,349] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: KafkaFileRead
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,381] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,397] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,398] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,484] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ***
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,485] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ***
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,486] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,486] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,487] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(***); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(***); groups with modify permissions: Set()
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,854] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 42261.
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,892] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,930] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,950] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,951] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,956] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
[2024-01-10 10:41:36,983] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:36 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-9b808eb1-ca31-478e-beba-702f3be274d5
[2024-01-10 10:41:37,009] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:37 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 434.4 MiB
[2024-01-10 10:41:37,028] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:37 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
[2024-01-10 10:41:37,272] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:37 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
[2024-01-10 10:41:37,397] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:37 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://84e9b84d3cce:4040
[2024-01-10 10:41:37,660] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:37 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark-master:7077...
[2024-01-10 10:41:37,743] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:37 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to spark-master/172.21.0.2:7077 after 56 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
[2024-01-10 10:41:57,661] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:41:57 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark-master:7077...
[2024-01-10 10:42:17,663] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:17 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark-master:7077...
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,664] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,665] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 WARN StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,675] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 43405.
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,675] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 84e9b84d3cce:43405
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,678] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,689] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://84e9b84d3cce:4040
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,693] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 84e9b84d3cce, 43405, None)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,697] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,701] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 84e9b84d3cce:43405 with 434.4 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 84e9b84d3cce, 43405, None)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,705] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,706] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 84e9b84d3cce, 43405, None)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,707] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 84e9b84d3cce, 43405, None)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,712] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Drop UnregisterApplication(null) because has not yet connected to master
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,728] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,747] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,748] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,758] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,762] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,775] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,900] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,900] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,900] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,900] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:89)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,901] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:613)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,901] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,901] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,901] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,901] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,901] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,902] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,902] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,902] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,902] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,902] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,902] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,902] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,902] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,902] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext already stopped.
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,903] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,903] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/opt/***/dags/src/dag/tasks/consumer.py", line 23, in <module>
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,903] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - main()
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,903] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/opt/***/dags/src/dag/tasks/consumer.py", line 7, in main
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,903] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('KafkaFileRead').getOrCreate()
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,903] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,903] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 392, in getOrCreate
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,903] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 147, in __init__
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,903] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 209, in _do_init
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,904] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 329, in _initialize_context
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,904] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1586, in __call__
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,904] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/home/***/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,904] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,904] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,904] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,904] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:89)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,904] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:613)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,905] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,905] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,905] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,905] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,905] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,905] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,905] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,905] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,905] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,906] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,906] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,906] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,906] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,906] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,949] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,949] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-fcf4c4dd-fda5-4567-9bc6-c4d46fd6515f
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,954] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/01/10 10:42:37 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-3ef104da-294f-4d9b-ac9a-54f01e0ad6e9
[2024-01-10 10:42:37,998] {taskinstance.py:1501} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1157, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1331, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1361, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/operators/spark_submit.py", line 157, in execute
    self._hook.submit(self._application)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py", line 420, in submit
    f"Cannot execute: {self._mask_cmd(spark_submit_cmd)}. Error code is: {returncode}."
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: spark-submit --master spark://spark-master:7077 --name arrow-spark /opt/***/dags/src/dag/tasks/consumer.py. Error code is: 1.
[2024-01-10 10:42:38,000] {taskinstance.py:1551} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=workflow, task_id=spark_submit_task, execution_date=20240110T104129, start_date=20240110T104133, end_date=20240110T104238
[2024-01-10 10:42:38,034] {local_task_job.py:149} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

I've tried several times fix something on the spark connection, but now i'm having doubts if the problem is really on this point.

Answer (score 1):

Python code of DAG running from the container not localhost so I think the problem here may be the docker network. You need to create a docker network and add all of your airflow containers and spark containers to the same network, run the command "docker network inspect network-name" to find the IP of your spark master.
Maybe these links help (same problem as DAG code needs to connect to an external system in the same docker network):

- https://medium.com/@rajat.mca.du.2015/airflow-and-mysql-with-docker-containers-80ed9c2bd340
- https://github.com/cyoung43/airflow-demo